# Compiling HTML string from directive at the time of loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, contextmenu

in Html:

```
<vs-context-menu id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu pointer-cursor" context-menu-hide></vs-context-menu>
```

in angular JS directive:

```
directive('vsContextMenu', function ($compile) {
    var defaultTemplate = '<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 20px;" ><li>AA</li></ul>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(defaultTemplate).show();
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Context menu is showing up on click fine. But it flashes at the loading of the page. How to hide it at the loading of the page?

Comment: ng-cloak https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: used `ng-cloak` at the element, it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rendering it using link function, do use `template` parameter of directive, this will not show flickering effect & also add `ng-cloak` on that element.

**Directive**

```
directive('vsContextMenu', function($compile) {
    var defaultTemplate = '<ul ng-cloak style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 20px;" ><li>AA</li></ul>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: defaultTemplate
    };
});
```